# ASP.NET MVC return empty view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the most natural way to return an empty ActionResult (for child action)?

```
public ActionResult TestAction(bool returnValue)
{
   if (!returnValue)
     return View(EmptyView);

   return View(RealView);
}
```

One option I can see is to create an empty view and reference it at EmptyView... but may be there is any built-in option?

Comment: Doesn't View() hav an option to return just text? If so, send an empty string.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

return instance of [EmptyResult class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult.aspx)

```
 return new EmptyResult();
```

Comment: In an action that returns `EmptyResult`, is it the same as doing `return null`?

Comment: @RobinMaben: No, null would not return an object from the method. EmptyResult however will.

Comment: I'd return `null` because internally, it will use the `internal` `EmptyResult.Instance` that you cannot access yourself. This saves repeated instantiation of a stateless object.

Answer (score 22):

You can return [EmptyResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult(v=vs.118).aspx) to return an empty view.

```
public ActionResult Empty()
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

You can also just return `null`. ASP.NET will [detect the return type `null` and will return an EmptyResult for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561189/340046).

```
public ActionResult Empty()
{
    return null;
}
```

See [MSDN documentation for ActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for list of ActionResult types you can return.

Answer (score 8):

if you want to return nothing you can do something like

```
if (!returnValue)
     return Content("");

   return View(RealView);
```

Comment: return new EmptyResult(); 
is the preferred approach