# return new EmptyResult() VS return NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action

in ASP.NET MVC when my action will not return anything I use `return new EmptyResult()`
or `return null`

is there any difference?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can return `null`. MVC will detect that and return an `EmptyResult`.

> MSDN: **EmptyResult** represents a result that doesn't do anything,
>   like a controller action returning null

#### Source code of MVC.

```
public class EmptyResult : ActionResult {

    private static readonly EmptyResult _singleton = new EmptyResult();

    internal static EmptyResult Instance {
        get {
            return _singleton;
        }
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
    }
}
```

And the source from `ControllerActionInvoker` which shows if you return null,
MVC will return `EmptyResult`.

```
protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue) {
    if (actionReturnValue == null) {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    ActionResult actionResult = (actionReturnValue as ActionResult) ??
        new ContentResult { Content = Convert.ToString(actionReturnValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
    return actionResult;
}
```

You can download the source code of the Asp.Net MVC Project on [Codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases).

Comment: What's with the internal singleton?

Answer (score 17):

When you return `null` from an action the MVC framework (actually the `ControllerActionInvoker` class) will internally create a new `EmptyResult`. So finally an  instance of the `EmptyResult` class will be used in both cases. So there is no real difference.

In my personal opinion `return new EmptyResult()` is better because it communicates more clearly that your action returns nothing.

Answer (score 8):

Artur,

both do basically the same in that the http header is sent back along with a blank page. you could however, tweak that further if you wished and return a new HttpStatusCodeResult() with the appropriate statusCode and statusDescription. i.e.:

```
var result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(999, "this didn't work as planned");
return result;
```

I think that may be a useful alternative.

**[edit]** - found a nice implementation of HttpStatusCodeResult() which exemplifies how to leverage this with google etc in mind:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/28/asp-net-mvc-3-using-httpstatuscoderesult.aspx

Comment: I like your approach and I have to add that we can use some predefined code from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes