# Clean way to return an empty mvc partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In cshtml file, based on a condition, what's the best way to return an empty partialview ?

Right now I have:

```
@if(Model.Count() > 0)
{
  loooonng partial view block of markup code
}
```

How can I re-do it to look cleaner closer to this:

```
@if(Model.Count() == 0)
{
  render an empty partial view
}

  loooonng partial view block of markup code goes here   <- This will obviously get executed only if Model.Count() > 0
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can try this return Content("");

Comment: How does the bottom code block look cleaner than the top?  It looks like you're in a Razor template, so the best way to render empty content is to not render anything... which is what your top code block is doing if `Model.Count() <= 0`

Comment: Because I would like to avoid having multiple runaway nested If statements. 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html

Comment: Does, return new EmptyResult(), work from a partial?  Never tried.

Comment: Empty result would return "empty result" from a controller, not render partial view from within the page. I think what Asif suggested below is the way to go. I'll try it in a bit.

Comment: duplicated as http://stackoverflow.com/a/6857674/2769693 it should be removed but I have no permission to do that

Comment: @WeiminYe This is not a duplicate, as the question you've pointed refers to an ActionResult and this question refers to a PartialView.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have been using

```
return Content("");
```

and is working fine.

Comment: Not working for me. Is this a Controller ActionResult or something ?

Comment: Its is Controller ActionResult. You should handle it at controller level.

Comment: If you're going to use return Content("") shouldn't you use ContentResult as the return type of the method?

Comment: cannot convert ContentResult to PartialViewResult :/

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but I came across this problem and here's what I did in the view:

```
@if(Model.Count() == 0)
{
return; // a simple return will stop execution of the rest of the View
}
```

On a Controller level, I created a new class and returned it in my action:

```
public class EmptyPartialViewResult : PartialViewResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you're returning a `PartialViewResult` I found that in the controller you can use

```
return default(PartialViewResult);
```

or

```
return null;
```

without any problems. The only consideration I can think is if you are using

```
var partialView = Html.Action("Action", "Controller");
```

in your view then you will need to check for null. `Html.RenderAction` appears to accept it no problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use [EmptyResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult(v=vs.118).aspx) class:

```
return new EmptyResult();
```

Comment: This won't compile if the controller method return type is PartialViewResult

Answer (score 1):

A view should not decide if it should be empty or contain something.  A view should be as "dumb" as possible, simply displaying the data from the model in a "fancy" way.  It is up to the controller to decided if the output should be empty or contain some data to display.  In other words, it is up to the controller to return an empty view or a non-empty view.

### Solution

Create an empty view (empty *.cshtml file) under Views/Shared:

> ```
> MVC_Project 
> ├── Views
>     ├── Shared
>         ├── _Empty.cshtml
> ```

Controller code:

```
public virtual PartialViewResult SomeAction()
{
    //some condition to determine if the view should be empty
    //maybe check if some properties of the model are null?
    if(returnEmptyView) 
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Empty.cshtml");

    return PartialView("~/Views/Something/NormalView.cshtml", model);
}
```