# How to return an empty razor page that uses a layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core Razor pages project that uses a `Layout` and wonder how would I return an empty page?

I tried something like

```
public ActionResult OnGet()
{
    return null;
}
```

but that only return empty section, it still show all of the layout elements.

Is there a way to return a completely empty page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870298/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-core-mvc

Comment: Altough it is not a duplicate since the problem is not even close, one of the answers actually provide an idea for workaround of this problem

Comment: Well, it doesn't need to be the same problem to solve, it can be one of its answers that make a post a possible duplicate, still, here's another possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC return empty view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857607/asp-net-mvc-return-empty-view)

Comment: put this in top of your cshtml file @{
    Layout = null;
 } and your action method must return your view file